# React: setState of array of object changes every item

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm building a memory game using React. I have an array of cards where each card can be "matching" (the user has just clicked on it) or "matched" (the user has found both cards and they are now completely shown). My issue is that when I try to set the matching state using `setState` the state changes for every card and not just the clicked one. Here's what I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Card from './card';

import './index.css';

class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cards: Array(4).fill(
                {
                    matching: false,
                    matched: false,
                }
            ),
            currentlyMatching: false,
        }
    }

    handleCardClick(index, type) {
        let currentCardsState = this.state.cards.slice();
        currentCardsState[index].matching = true;
        this.setState({cards: currentCardsState});
    }

    renderCard(index, type) {
        return <Card value={type}
        matching={this.state.cards[index].matching}
        matched={this.state.cards[index].matched} // this line is the issue
        onClick={() => this.handleCardClick(index, type)}
        />;
    };

    render() {
        return <div id="game">
            {this.renderCard(0,"red")}
            {this.renderCard(1, "green")}
            {this.renderCard(2, "red")}
            {this.renderCard(3, "green")}
        </div>;
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Game />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: No you can ignore matched completely for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are not creating 4 independent objects for every card. You are creating *one* object which appears in the array four times. That means that changing any index affects all indices.

That's how `Array.fill` works.

To create four independent states, you need something like this:

```
const cards = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  cards.push({
    matched: false,
    matching: false
  ));
}
```

Comment: This. Thanks, I copied the fill part from reacts tutorial (which in the end is another game) without really realizing what it does.

I just went with writing the matching and matched 4 times by hand, cause in the end they'll all have an additional "imageUrl" attribute to make them all look different. Thanks

Comment: @JonasGiuro This is one of the reasons why using immutables is a good idea. Even when creating the same 4 objects at the start, mutating one using immutable primitives would create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `shouldComponentUpdate` to each `Card` component to prevent unnecessary re-renders:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    return prevProps !== this.props
}
```

Or you can specifically target a single prop:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    return prevProps.matched !== this.props.matched
}
```

Answer (score -1):

And this is exactly what is expected: you are setting in the state a new array of objects and for this reason the render is called again for each of them